# unable to execute query in omnidb

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm using OmniDB from my company server. But queries are not executing. It will go running the whole day and still won't execute. If I click on cancel tab, then also noting happens. What's wrong?
[image: I tried executing the same query yesterday also but it doesn't even give error for using wrong tablename]

Answer (score 0):

You need to force close the omnidb panel and then restart again.

And execute query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM `abc`.`XYZ` limit 1;
```

`abc` is database, and `XYZ` is your table name.